# Coordinates of all 'N' points, equidistant from each other , on a circle of radius 'R' whose center is (h,v) from the origin?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> How would I calculate the coordinates of all 'n points' equidistant from each other on a circle of radius r and the center  coordinates of  (h,v) from the origin .

Answer (score 1):

If you want one of the points to be directly to the left of center, the points are $(h+r \cos \frac {2\pi}i,v+r \sin \frac {2\pi}i)$ for $i \in [0,n-1]$